# Ambiguous symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have declared a class Integer in a custom namespace:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
  class Integer {};
}
```

And I am using it in a method like this:

```
void someMethod()
{
  using namespace MyNameSpace;
  SomeClass x(Integer("some text", 4));
}
```

This gives

```
10> error C2872: 'Integer' : ambiguous symbol
10>        could be 'g:\lib\boost\boost_1_47_0\boost/concept_check.hpp(66) : boost::Integer'
10>        or       '[my file] : MyNameSpace::Integer'
```

I have searched my code base for "namespace boost" and "using boost" with fulltext search but didn't find a line like "using namespace boost;". This is supported by the test that

```
void someMethod()
{
  shared_ptr<int> x;
  using namespace MyNameSpace;
  //SomeClass x(Integer("some text", 4));
}
```

gives

```
error C2065: 'shared_ptr' : undeclared identifier
```

whereas

```
void someMethod()
{
  boost::shared_ptr<int> x;
  using namespace MyNameSpace;
  //SomeClass x(Integer("some text", 4));
}
```

compiles.

Is there any other reason why the "ambiguous symbol" error can occur??

Comment: Isn't "Integer" a reserved word ??

Comment: There could be a ``using boost::Integer`` somewhere.

Comment: Try and specify `MyNameSpace::Integer` in `SomeClass x(Integer(4));` in order to tell the compiler this is the Integer you want.

Comment: @juanchopanza: This is why I searched for "using boost".

Comment: @fritzone: I know this, but I am instantiating several "Integer"s and would like to avoid the nasty qualifier.

Comment: Nitpick: "namespace" is a single word, so don't capitalize the 's'. ;) Question: Are you actually initializing the `Integer` class with a literal `4` or something else? ADL could trick you here. Although, if you initialize it with a variable, that should trigger the most-vexing-parse and not an "ambiguous symbol" error.. hmm...

Comment: then try and put someMethod in the namespace MyNameSpace. I think that in this case the symbols from the same namespace might have priority.

Comment: @Philipp: Rather than searching the code base, try searching the preprocessed source file. It could be hidden, perhaps by a marco, or in a header that your global search missed. If that fails, try removing code until the error goes away; you'll either find the problem, or end up with a test case suitable to post here.

Comment: edit: Actually the arguments to the constructor are (char*, int)

Comment: "This is supported by the test that" -- could you test with `Integer`, without the `using namespace MyNameSpace;`? It should give an undeclared identifier error, but if it still picks up `boost::Integer`, you've got to be `using` it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler just prevents you from mixing this classes up. Even when you are not using namespace "boost".

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are essentially "last names" or "family names" for the stuff in them.  In your case Integer()'s whole name is MyNameSpace::Integer().  You specific errors are a splendid example of the first rule of using namespaces.  DO NOT USE "USING" STATEMENTS!  If you leave them out completely, yes, you have to type a few extra things to placate the compiler.  But you never have collisions or to ask anything like "does boost have an Integer somewhere".

Secondly, someMethod() is outside any class and outside any namespace.  It really ought to look more like **MyNameSpace::Integer::someMethod(**) or more reasonably be inside a

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
   Integer::someMethod(
}
```

Once you do this, the compiler WILL help you find where stuff is or isn't.

Good luck!